# How to add space to left-right of the Web-Page using HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, web

[image]

I want to add space in the HTML document like the ones inside the orange rectangle. I don't know the technical term for what it's professionally called. Apologies.

Comment: Do you want to center your main document or do you want to fill that space with other things?

Comment: I want to center my documents and leave those space empty.

Comment: `float` the two ad spaces and `margin:auto` the main content - simples!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are looking to center your web page and you are using a fixed width on your main container this can easily be achieved.

CSS

```
.container {
   margin:0 auto; /* this will center the page */
   width:960px; /*  use your width here */
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- all your great content here -->
    </div>
</body>
```

If you need help applying this to your html/css please post your html and I would be glad to help you.

Answer (score 8):

Why not do this? :

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    body {
        padding: 0 20px;
    }

    #main {
        margin: 0 auto; /* in case you want to set a fixed width on this as well */
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="main"></div>
</body>
```

This way, depending on the width on the window, the main div will resize and there will always be a fixed space on both sides. If you want the main div have a fixed width and the spacing on the sides to be resized automatically, use the other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Those would be margins.  But your better option would be to wrap the main area in a div or other block element/sectioning root, set it to the width that you want, and then center it with `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: That means the width of the main div has to be fixed, and won't change with the width of the window changing...

Comment: My answer was the same as the one that's getting upvoted now, I don't know how you misread it.

Comment: Yeah, and I don't agree with it either. I think the <body> should have padding

Comment: The body with padding won't scale down to a conceivably smaller display.  You'd always have the padding which effectively get in the way of the relevant display elements.

Comment: Yeah and with a fixed width, the page will never scale "up", unless you know the resolution of the users........

Comment: Then you'd be looking for a percentage based width.  Optionally you could also use a percentage based padding which makes both arguments subject to the same issue.  In most sites I've dealt with however there are far more arguments for wrapping the main page body in a fixed width so other things can be worked with a more controlled environment: and the site in the screenshot above appears to also be subject to that focus.  The container also provides an additional qualifier and target for further styling.  It is also more conceptually aligned with the display (as things are visually contained)

Comment: Hey, there's plenty of arguments on why you'd want to set a fixed width on the main area, or not. It's really based on the situation. I'm not saying you shouldn't wrap the content in a main div - I always do that at least, but it's not always the only solution to the problem to make things fixed.

Answer (score 1):

you need margins. set the style to `margin:0 auto;` that will center your div